# cannot add new node to existing galera cluster

Tags: galera

in the error file i have this.

WSREP: wsrep_load(): loading provider library 'none'

but in the config file /etc/mysql/config.d/galera.conf has this

```
[mysqld]
#mysql settings
binlog_format=ROW
default-storage-engine=innodb
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=0
bind-address=0.0.0.0
#galera settings
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_name="pivotrac_cluster"
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://192.168.1.113,192.168.1.119,192.168.1.126,192.168.1.129"
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
wsrep_sst_auth=geek:snape99
wsrep_sst_donor='dot129'
wsrep_provider_options=”gcache.size = 5G”
```

and the file /usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so  is present.

any ideas?

here is the relevent info in the log file

```
140926 13:40:52 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140926 13:40:52 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140926 13:40:52 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
140926 13:40:52 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
140926 13:40:52 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 100.0G
140926 13:40:57 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140926 13:40:57 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
140926 13:41:01  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
140926 13:41:02 Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.5.38-MariaDB-35.2 started; log sequence number 1598129
140926 13:41:02 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
140926 13:41:02 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
140926 13:41:02 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
140926 13:41:02 [Note] WSREP: Read nil XID from storage engines, skipping position init
140926 13:41:02 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): loading provider library 'none'
140926 13:41:02 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.39-MariaDB-1~trusty-wsrep'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution, wsrep_25.10.r4014
```

some notes 
this server is ubuntu 14.04 the others are 12.04  ( i was hoping to upgrade their OS one at a time)

i can still log into the mariadb server with root username and password..

hope someone can help me on this.. thanks all

Answer (score 1):

Your `galera.conf` should be named `galera.cnf` in order for MySQL to load it, assuming your primary MySQL configuration (`/etc/mysql/my.cnf`) has a `!includedir /etc/mysql/config.d/`.

Comment: I cannot believe I made this stupid error.  So many thanks for giving me the pointer.  If you're ever in New Zealand, I owe you a Chocolate Fish (the standard unit of gratitude out here) ;)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue yesterday. There are two places you need to check:

1. Make sure that the file /usr/lib/galera/libgalera_smm.so exists cos it would be located in /usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so for x64 platform
2. Move these settings to /etc/mysql/config.d/server.cnf instead of //etc/mysql/config.d/galera.cnf

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help on this, it has been a mystery ever since it happened. I did wind up doing a re-install, and that worked too. I will keep these notes though, because i will be rebuilding two servers later this month.